# C#: Why don't string and List support serialization?

Tags: c#, string, list, serialization, compilation

I'm using C# 8 with new features enables, having this code snippet:

```
[Serializable]
class Inner
{
    public readonly int mI;
    public readonly string s = "abc"; // doesn't compile
    public Inner(int i) { mI = i; }
}

[Serializable]
class Outter
{
    public readonly List<Inner> li = new List<Inner>() // doesn't compile
    {
        new Inner(2),
        new Inner(3)
    };
}
```

It doesn't compile and says:

> Field s is a member of type Inner which is serializable but is of type string which is not serializable.

and

> Field li is a member of type Outter which is serializable but is of type System.Collections.Generic.List which is not serializable.

So why does it say "string" cannot be serialized, what's the problem with my code and how do I fix it?

---

I get this error because my project has "Directory.build.target" rule set for code analysis as below:

true
      8.0
      enable
      false

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RootPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory.TrimEnd("\").TrimEnd("/"))</RootPath>
  <OutputFolder>$(RootPath)/out</OutputFolder>
  <DropOutputFolder>$(OutputFolder)/drop</DropOutputFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <Include>xxxxx</Include>
  <ExcludeByAttribute>ObsoleteAttribute,GeneratedCodeAttribute,CompilerGeneratedAttribute</ExcludeByAttribute>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The error is from the code analyser:

```
Error   CA2235  Field li is a member of type Outter which is serializable but is of type System.Collections.Generic.List<NUnitTestProject_core.Inner> which is not serializable
```

Hope this time it's clear. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the compiler error that you are getting? I can't reproduce it at my end

Comment: I also have no compile error!  What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: please show us more code c# has dozens of serializers of with many support the native dataannotations like `Serializable`.

Comment: Does it work without ReadOnly?

Comment: It seems, that you are getting [CA2235](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2235?view=vs-2019) warning. Why are treating it as an error? I don't think that it's related to C# 8

Comment: I've edited my post, the problem shows when global code analysis is enabled, as in my post. Thanks.

Comment: @Troskyvs you can simply fix it by converting the fields to read-only properties, but CA2235 should not be thrown here, since both `string` and `List<T>` are marked as [Serializable]

Answer (score 0):

I found that place a field attribute of [NonSerialized] will solve this compile error